# Using jQuery ajax with vb.net 2.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I try to do use Ajax (through jQuery) in asp.net website (using vb.net 2.0).

Here is my .aspx page (ajax.aspx):

```
    <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ajax.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Ajax" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Calling page methods with jQuery</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #Result {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="Result">Click here for the time.</div>

  <script src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script>
      $('#Result').click(function () {
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "ajax.aspx/HelloWorld",
              data: "{}",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (msg) {
                  // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                  $("#Result").text(msg.d);
              },
              error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                  alert("xhr.responseText= " + xhr.responseText);
                  alert("xhr.responseStatus= " + xhr.responseStatus);
                  alert("thrownError= " + thrownError);
              }
          });
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is code-behind file (ajax.aspx.vb):

```
    Imports System
Imports System.Web.Services

Public Class _Ajax
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load()

    End Sub

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function HelloWorld() As String
        Return "Hello: "
    End Function

End Class
```

When I click on my div, ajax call failed with:

**System.ArgumentException: Unknown web method HelloWorld.**

**[EDIT]**

After refresh and restart browser a lot of times, web method is found!

I try now to add a new web method, but I get error "unknown web method" again.

I think it's a cache problem.

Do you know how to force disable this kind of cache ?

Comment: you might be missing some web.config value( httpmodules) , can you see you can access scriptmanager in your page.If not you need to install ajax extension for you application.

Comment: You're right, it's better (but not enought) after installing Ajax for ASP.NET 2.0

Comment: You problem get solved ? or still you have some issues

Comment: It's not solved. I get error "Unknown web method". I edited my first post to describe it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, paritosh answer was useful.

I had to install ASP.NET Ajax 1.0 on web server using ASP.NET 2.0.

Here is the link : 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=883

Then, web method is not found until i restart ISS website, I don't know why, but it's OK after restarting it.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ajax.aspx.vb"
 Inherits="_Ajax" %>
```

to

```
 <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ajax.aspx.vb"
 Inherits="_Ajax" ScriptManager.EnablePageMethods="true" %>
```

This will make all the web methods on this page visible to the JavaScript client.

Comment: EnablePageMethods is not available for ASP.NET 2.0.